# fix div position when it scrolled to its end using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

There are three column in my website and they can not be balanced from bottom.
I just want the div to be fixed once it scrolls all over and let another div scrollable.

Sorry if I failed to explain the issue clearly.
Please have a look at this website: http://scoopwhoop.com

Comment: show your code effort.

Comment: If we can watch the code on your site, why don't you take it from there to show us? Your question could be easily flagged as spam!

Comment: sorry! I don't have code, I need code to done my task.

Comment: Please write some code first. If you have no idea where to start, have a look at the `position` page on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/position) or use the stackoverflow search to find similar problems. If you still get stuck, update your post and show your code here, then people can actually help you.

Comment: @user3704899 stackoverflow isn't a site where you say: I need this - go on - do it. It's a site where you share your problems during coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need changed position for div.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var scrollTop = $("body").scrollTop();
        if ( bo > 800 ) $('.div').css('position','fixed');
        })
    })
```